# How to Add user Metadata as order metadata in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm trying to add Metadata  that my resellers enter and save on their profiles to my orders. Resellers enter VAT number which is saved as metadata on the reseller's user profile.

I'm trying to get this metadata to show as order metadata. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
// Add VAT Number as Order Meta Data

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'wwp_customer_meta_data', 10, 2 );
function wwp_customer_meta_data( $order, $data ) {
    $user_id  = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the user id
    $wwp_vat = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wwp_wholesaler_tax_id', true );
    $order->update_meta_data( 'VAT Number', $wwp_vat );
}
```

Comment: How is `$post_id` defined?

Comment: I've updated my code but I still can't seem to get the VAT number to show as meta. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: How is `wwp_wholesaler_tax_id` getting posted to the checkout?

Comment: It's not posted on checkout. It's already saved to the customer profile when they create a reseller account. So the data is already on the user account. I'm trying to add user metadata as order metadata.

Comment: Try using woocommerce_thankyou hook instead. Your latest code version should work

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502896/3821467

Comment: So my code actually does work. It just doesn't work when you create an order from the order admin page. But if you create an order from the front end (as customer), it works just fine.

Comment: By the way, your suggestion of using the woocommerce_thankyou hook, created an error on the thank you page. This is how you would do it using woocommerce_thankyou: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388921/adding-user-custom-field-to-the-order-meta-data-automatically/41389064#41389064

Comment: the thankyou hook only passes the orderid.  So you'd have to get the order object from that.